# ReactJs no-undef for all imported packages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm building a project with ReactJS and started with a very simple code to test my project setup:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class App extends Component {

    state = {
        test: null
    }

    componentWillMount = () => {
        this.setState({
            test: "Hello World!"
        })
    }

    render = () => {
        return (
                <div>
                    <p>{this.state.test}</p>
                </div>
                );
    }    
}

export default App;
```

When I run (yarn start), all my imports are not being recognized:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/pages/App/App.js
  Line 18:  'state' is not defined               no-undef
  Line 22:  'componentWillMount' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 28:  'render' is not defined              no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

My package.json (inherited from another project that works):

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/",
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.1",
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-relay": "^1.4.1",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.0.3",
    "babel-runtime": "6.23.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^1.0.5",
    "eslint-loader": "1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.34.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.1.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "fixed-data-table-2": "^0.8.13",
    "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
    "graphql": "^0.13.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "moment": "^2.19.1",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "0.0.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.1",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.6",
    "promise": "7.1.1",
    "react": "^15.6.2",
    "react-datetime": "^2.11.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^3.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.2",
    "react-error-overlay": "^1.0.10",
    "react-fa": "^4.2.0",
    "react-relay": "^1.4.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-relay": "^0.14.0",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.19.1",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.3",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "validator": "^9.1.1",
    "webpack": "2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.5.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "relay-compiler": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive --follow",
    "start-js": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build-js": "node scripts/build.js",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "build": "npm-run-all build-css build-js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom",
    "relay": "relay-compiler --src ./src --schema ./graphql/schema.graphql"
  },
  "babel": {
    "plugins": [
      "relay"
    ],
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
}
```

And my script:

```
'use strict';

// Do this as the first thing so that any code reading it knows the right env.
process.env.BABEL_ENV = 'development';
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';

// Makes the script crash on unhandled rejections instead of silently
// ignoring them. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will
// terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
  throw err;
});

// Ensure environment variables are read.
require('../config/env');

const fs = require('fs');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
const clearConsole = require('react-dev-utils/clearConsole');
const checkRequiredFiles = require('react-dev-utils/checkRequiredFiles');
const {
  choosePort,
  createCompiler,
  prepareProxy,
  prepareUrls,
} = require('react-dev-utils/WebpackDevServerUtils');
const openBrowser = require('react-dev-utils/openBrowser');
const paths = require('../config/paths');
const config = require('../config/webpack.config.dev');
const createDevServerConfig = require('../config/webpackDevServer.config');

const useYarn = fs.existsSync(paths.yarnLockFile);
const isInteractive = process.stdout.isTTY;

// Warn and crash if required files are missing
if (!checkRequiredFiles([paths.appHtml, paths.appIndexJs])) {
  process.exit(1);
}

// Tools like Cloud9 rely on this.
const DEFAULT_PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const HOST = process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0';

// We attempt to use the default port but if it is busy, we offer the user to
// run on a different port. `detect()` Promise resolves to the next free port.
choosePort(HOST, DEFAULT_PORT)
  .then(port => {
    if (port == null) {
      // We have not found a port.
      return;
    }
    const protocol = process.env.HTTPS === 'true' ? 'https' : 'http';
    const appName = require(paths.appPackageJson).name;
    const urls = prepareUrls(protocol, HOST, port);
    // Create a webpack compiler that is configured with custom messages.
    const compiler = createCompiler(webpack, config, appName, urls, useYarn);
    // Load proxy config
    const proxySetting = require(paths.appPackageJson).proxy;
    const proxyConfig = prepareProxy(proxySetting, paths.appPublic);
    // Serve webpack assets generated by the compiler over a web sever.
    const serverConfig = createDevServerConfig(
      proxyConfig,
      urls.lanUrlForConfig
    );
    const devServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, serverConfig);
    // Launch WebpackDevServer.
    devServer.listen(port, HOST, err => {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      if (isInteractive) {
        clearConsole();
      }
      console.log(chalk.cyan('Starting the development server...\n'));
      openBrowser(urls.localUrlForBrowser);
    });

    ['SIGINT', 'SIGTERM'].forEach(function(sig) {
      process.on(sig, function() {
        devServer.close();
        process.exit();
      });
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    if (err && err.message) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Why is my importing not being recognized? Am I missing some parameter/configuration?

The same package.json and start script is being used successfully in another project with ReactJs....

Comment: Why not use `create-react-app`?

Comment: The scrips and package.json originally comes from an ejected create-react-app. This is the beggining as I will be tweaking it later... But first I need to find out what is wrong with this basic scenario...

Comment: So why not start with a fresh app, created by `create-react-app`? Why are you trying to solve a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the plugins under `babelrc`

```
"plugins": [ "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties" ]
```